# How can you fix a header in InDesign so content scrolls underneath?

Tags: adobe-indesign, layout, interaction

I have a one page InDesign document with a top navigation element similar to a website that I want to fix and have content pass underneath when a user scrolls through the PDF, is this possible?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: I'm about 99% sure that this is not possible with a PDF.  I would say 100%, but there may be some crazy script or something that I've never heard of.  Does it have to be a PDF?  You could always build a simple webpage, if you have a domain and hosting available.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Fixed-Layout ePub (good on any device) or DPS (single edition, only on iPad), but not with Interactive PDF. There isn't a whole lot of animation available in the PDF format, and FXL ePub definitely looks set to become the more general standard, if only because it's based on HTML, CSS and javascript.